# Get resource id from which view was inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-resources

Is there a way to obtain the resources id (like R.layout.viewtoInflate) of the layout from which a view was inflated?

I am trying to implement a List View that uses 2 custom layouts for the list items. Which item layout is used is based on a field in the objects used to populate the list view.

What I am missing in my custom adapter is a way to know what resource the 'convertView' I get in the getView() was inflated from. If I could get that info I can compare and determine whether I can re-use the convert view as it is or if I have to replace it with the appropriate  layout for the current item.

So ideally it would be something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    JSONObject currItem = mItems.getJSONObject(position);

    int layoutType;

    if (currItem.getBoolean("alternate"))
        layoutType = R.layout.list_item_b;
    else
        layoutType = R.layout.list_item_a;

    if (convertView == null || <convertView.resourceID> != layoutType ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutType, null);

        //Finish setting up new View and its holder
    }
    else {
        //Get view holder for view reuse
    }

    //populate view with the required content

    return convertView;
}
```

At worst I could just not re-use views at all and just inflate the layout I need every time, but it seems very wasteful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an official way to use multiple layouts, simply override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.  These methods inform the Adapter to expect multiple layouts and `convertView` will always be the appropriate layout (so don't need to check the resource id.)  Please see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13297339/1267661) for some sample code.

But if you want to find out which layout is which, simply check for a unique characteristic.  For example you can use `findViewById()` on a View that only exists in one layout, then check whether it returns `null` or not.

Comment: I don't understand how I missed this multi-layout functionality but thank you. Also thanks for the suggestion for finding the layout type, no longer needed for now, but good to know anyway. Still, it seems odd to me that there is no official way of getting the layout of an inflated view.

Answer (score 3):

List view supports multiple layouts - you need to return count of layouts used in `getViewTypeCount()` and correct layout type for the row in `getItemViewType()`.

And if you want still to know what layout it was inflated from, then you can attach any information to the view using `setTag()` and retrieve it later using `getTag()` - it can be your layoutId or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is save the resource Id of the inflated view in the view holder when creating the view. This allows me to get the layout resource ID when I am populating the views.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for getting id's of items from the layout which you have inflated. It goes like this:-

```
//Suppose you have an TextView in the inflated layout of id textView1. Here you go

convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutType, null);
TextView tv = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: How does the above code return the id of the inflated item. findviewbyid returns the view only and not the id