# How to show profile picture in slide menu?

Tags: android, menu

I'm going on with my menu slider bar action and for that I had Googled and finished my slide bar action with help of the below link

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Now what i need is to add a profile image and user name with his location (eg:image,john,Chennai) in top of the list.
I tried that by creating seperate relative layout for the above three and another separate layout for the rest of list items but i am getting some alignment issues.

[image]

here is my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     >
     <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/userimage_top"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/usermenu_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            androidaddingLeft="5dp"
            androidrc="@drawable/profile_circle" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usermenu_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usermenu_image"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="@color/lightred"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/user_location"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignRight="@+id/usermenu_image"
       android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
       android:text="loication"
       android:textColor="@color/lightred"
       android:textSize="15dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/userimage_menu"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
              android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/userimage_top" >

             <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        androidrc="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        androidaddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>


       </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        androidivider="@color/list_divider"
        androidividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/side_menu_panel"/>
       </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

so can any one please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Create another similar XML file, with `ImageView`'s height/width according to your desired image's dimensions. Then in `Adapter`'s `getView` method, set your image to the `ImageView`.

Comment: another XML file means how can i show it in the same view sorry i can't get you can u plz show me sample

Comment: Why are you not using `ListView` to achieve the required?

Comment: already i'm getting the titles and images in listview only

Comment: The XML layout is you list row layout, right?

Comment: yes i'll update my other XML also for your reference now

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: ok let me try it out and know for you..

Comment: no bro already i'ad tried it can change only specific now i'm going on with other ideas to change the alignment by code wise and let me know for u.

Comment: Before that, have a look at this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297299/reusing-views-in-android-listview-with-2-different-layouts

Comment: yes in code wise i tried with setting the position and change the height and of each rows but now i'm going to set empty linear layout and set the imageview textview alignment by code wise default.

Comment: There can be multiple approaches, but the 2nd link, I mentioned, certainly addresses your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i'ad acheived it by myself by using the custom ListView in slide bar menu.