# How to set different layout pattern in the RecycleLayout?

Tags: android, view, adapter, android-recyclerview

Generally, the recylceLayout is similar to listview and show the same content, however, I wonder are there any way to do like this

1) For odd item , use odd_item.xml layout, and run odd_item action only getView
2) For even, use even_item.xml layout, and run even_item action only in getView

This is the Java,

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_list, container, false);

        app = (MyApp) getActivity().getApplication() ;

        StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Constant.get_news_list,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        items = new ArrayList<Item>();

                        try {
                            JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(s);
                            for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject object = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                items.add(new Item(object.getString("id"), object.getString("title_tw"), object.getString("image_url")));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        setupRecyclerView(rv);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.network_err), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        app.mQueue.add(getRequest);

        return rv;
    }


    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), items));
    }

    public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        private int mBackground;
        private List<Item> mValues;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public String id;

            public final View mView;
            public final ImageView mImageView;
            public final TextView mTextView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                mView = view;
                mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
            }
        }

        public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
            mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
            mValues = items;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_item_even, parent, false);
            view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.id = mValues.get(position).id;
            holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position).name);

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", holder.id);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                    .load(Constant.blog_dir + mValues.get(position).img)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(holder.mImageView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mValues.size();
        }
    }
```

How to customized for that? Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getItemViewType(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method of the adapter. By the properties of the element from the adapter at given position, return a pre-defined integer value from this method (so, for example, for even positions return some `public static final int VIEW_EVEN = 0` etc). This value will be passed to `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` as the `viewType` parameter. That enables you to return different subclasses of `ViewHolder` from this method, depending on the `viewType` value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `getViewTypeCount` and `getItemViewType(int position)` functions and then inflate separate layouts for odd and even positions.

Refer to this link: [Reusing views in Android Listview with 2 different layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297299/reusing-views-in-android-listview-with-2-different-layouts)